# How to pass a list variable to subprocess.call command in Python

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a list

```
apps = []
apps.append("wq35a5huqlja45jsyukrpmwuiayovrmh")
apps.append("q7mimvgduueernwvw4y22t5huemykntw")
apps.append("pmudbpyquna2bll53pwqh7gdejxtmchq")
```

I want to pass this list variable to a linux command, sth like this.

```
subprocess.call(["service", "delete", apps])
```

But I am getting following error.

> TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings

I tried this as well, but again it's not working.

```
subprocess.call("service delete $apps", shell=True)
```

Can someone please let me know how to pass a variable(list, dictionary e.t.c) to subprocess.call command

Comment: `subprocess.call(["service", "delete"] + apps)`?

Comment: What is the expected syntax for service? If you can call it with `subprocess` you can call it directly, so what would be the command line?

Answer (score 1):

```
subprocess.call(["service", "delete", *apps])
```

will expand to

```
subprocess.call(["service", "delete", "wq35a5huqlja45jsyukrpmwuiayovrmh", ...])
```

Answer (score 0):

> subprocess.call("service delete $apps", shell=True)

This is wrong because `apps` is not a shell variable. Passing a python string variable works out of the box.

```
In[12]: daemon = 'ntp'
In[13]: sb.call(["service", daemon, "status"])
● ntp.service - LSB: Start NTP daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ntp; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-03-04 01:37:43 IST; 1 day 13h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2045 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/ntp start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 1
   Memory: 2.1M
      CPU: 6.816s
   CGroup: /system.slice/ntp.service
           └─2345 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 123:130

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
Out[13]: 0
```

However to pass anything other than strings you would have to manually do some type conversion, so for lists you would have to do something like this.

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> sb.call(["echo", ','.join(a)])
a,b,c
0
```

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted Harly H's answer, but just for completeness, here's another way.

```
subprocess.run(['xargs', '-0', 'service', 'delete'],
    input='\0'.join(apps)),
    check=True,   # probably a good idea, but not strictly required
    universal_newlines=True)
```

This requires a Python new enough to have `subprocess.run()` though something similar is easy or at least possible even with the Python 2 `subprocess` interface.  In 3.7+ `universal_newlines` is more aptly labelled `text`.

`xargs` will also take care of avoiding any "argument list too long" errors if `apps` is a really long string. (Google for `ARG_MAX`.)